# Why am I having segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I am working with this type (new at it):

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;
```

And I was trying to do a function that takes ordered "LInt" and merge them into one ordered "LInt".

```
void merge (LInt *r, LInt l1, LInt l2){

    LInt aux=*r;
    for (; l1!=NULL && l2!=NULL;aux=aux->prox){
        if (l1->valor <= l2->valor){ aux->valor=l1->valor, l1=l1->prox;}
        else {aux->valor=l2->valor, l2=l2->prox;}
    }
    while (l1!=NULL){
        aux->valor=l1->valor;
        l1=l1->prox;
        aux=aux->prox;
    }
    while (l2!=NULL){
        aux->valor=l2->valor;
        l2=l2->prox;
        aux=aux->prox;
    }
    aux=NULL;
}
```

I'm having segmentation fault and I don't know why.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Now is a good time to lean how to use a debugger. It is your most important tool. Really.

Comment: What @OldProgrammer says above, for sure.  That, and did you mean 'LInt aux=*r;'?  What is type of  'r'?    Did you maybe mean '&r' ??

Comment: @c650 i would love to, but I'm using codeboard and it seems like i can't see what the tests are, it just says if you done well or now (university teachers idea)

Comment: For this to work, `r` must be a pointer to an already existing linked list with a mininum length of the sum of then lenghts of `l1`  and `l2`.

Comment: `aux->valor=l1->valor, l1=l1->prox;` Are you sure that should be a comma? It looks like it should be a semicolon. It shouldn't be a problem, but it looks a bit odd.

Comment: @Bruno giving out software development assignmetns without access to a debugger is like soccer practice with no pitch.  Tell your teacher s/he's an.. no, just say it's silly.

Comment: **Never ever** `typedef` a data pointer!

Comment: @ThingyWotsit r is the 1st argument and it's LInt *r, but I say LInt aux=*r because for me it's an easy way to work at the beginning.

Comment: @IanAbbott i guess it can be yeah, but It doesn't solve the issue that I'm having!

Comment: I think the segmentation fault is due to something outside the code you posted.

Comment: @ErichKitzmueller i did forgot about allocating memmory yeah...

Comment: Do you need to keep the original lists `l1` and `l2` after the merge, or are you allowed to destroy them while creating the merged list?

Comment: @IanAbbott I can see now a test, and the test is
Input: [ ] + [  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 ]
Output: expected [  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15 17 19 ]
        obtained [ ]

Comment: @IanAbbott I'm allowed to destroy them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is (one phase of) a destructive merge sort.  It moves the elements of lists `l1` and `l2` (which are already sorted) onto the merged list.

```
typedef struct lligada {
    int valor;
    struct lligada *prox;
} *LInt;

void merge(LInt *r, LInt l1, LInt l2) {
    while (l1 && l2) {
        if (l1->valor <= l2->valor) {
            *r = l1;
            l1 = l1->prox;
        } else {
            *r = l2;
            l2 = l2->prox;
        }
        r = &(*r)->prox;
    }
    if (l1) {
        *r = l1;
    } else {
        *r = l2;
    }
}
```

An alternative to assigning `r = &(*)->prox;` after the `if/else` statement, is to assign `r` within the `if` and `else` parts, e.g.:

```
        if (l1->valor <= l2->valor) {
            *r = l1;
            r = &l1->prox; // <-- this and ...
            l1 = l1->prox;
        } else {
            *r = l2;
            r = &l2->prox; // <-- ... this are alternative ... 
            l2 = l2->prox;
        }
        // r = &(*r)->prox; // <-- ... to this
```